# Libgit2sharp equivalent of 'git gc'?

Tags: libgit2sharp

We have 100+ remote repositories that we are looking to operate on exclusively via libgit2sharp but need to keep the repositories as small as possible. We were intending to just set gc.auto low and let git handle running garbage collection when the repositories got to big but after some tests we noticed that libgit2sharp didn't support that config setting. Upon further investigation I noticed that someone already pretty much already asked about libgit2sharp's support of the gc.auto config here:

[is libgit2 automatically packing repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614878/is-libgit2-automatically-packing-repositories)

While I understand the reasoning in that response I was wondering is there a way to manually force a garbage collection on a repository via libgit2sharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering is there a way to manually force a garbage collection on a repository via libgit2sharp?

There's no way to request a garbage collection at this moment. 
Some required low level functions already exist at the libgit2 level, but most of the logic has yet to be implemented.

No entry exist yet in the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)** about a `git gc`-like API. The best way for you to be kept updated about this topic would be to log a new feature request.