# How to get a list of Ostream or Oinfo in a variable from a repository path in gitpython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I currently have a valid git database with no packfile, but due to a bug in`git-pack-objects`*(the process crashes with a stack dump file)* I’m unable to perform the`git repack`command.

I took a look at the error, and it’s linked to the C nature of the official git project *(fixing would require changing core`struct`definitions)* so, this will takes a lot of time to fix.

The only alternative I found which don’t use C is gitdb *(part of gitpython)*. However I wasn’t able to find how to use the[`write_pack()`](http://gitdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#gitdb.pack.PackEntity.write_pack)function.
Or more exactly, I have no idea on how to build the[`object_iter`](http://gitdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#gitdb.pack.PackEntity.create)parameter from the database path from loose objects.
I don’t even know the exact class type used in the[`object_iter`](http://gitdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#gitdb.pack.PackEntity.create)list.

So, how to use gitdb for that purpose ?

Comment: Did you try another version of git? I think all available git libraries are using the original git implementation in their heart

Comment: @DanielAlder : the bug is still unfixed in mainline : there are even security implication, so I won’t tell more about it here. The point is will takes weeks to get it fixed.

Comment: @user2284570 you could try to look at the tests for `write_pack()` [here](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/gitdb/blob/master/gitdb/test/test_pack.py#L213) and [here](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/gitdb/blob/master/gitdb/test/performance/test_pack_streaming.py#L58). Please note that `write_pack()` doesn't actually decrease the pack size by computing deltas, but store each object in its full, compressed size.

Comment: @Byron : it’s not for getting lower size usage. Packfiles are required for many things in git, including network operations like pushing. You can’t do that with loose objects. Also what I can’t is building the parameter from loose objects. Your examples only explain how to do it with existing packfiles *(due to to functions I was already away of)*, not from only loose objects. I couldn’t found any function returning an Ostream without requiring an existing packfile *(or at least, I misread the documentation)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
#/usr/bin/python
import os,sys,zlib,gitdb
from gitdb.db import LooseObjectDB
from gitdb.pack import PackEntity
from gitdb.util import bin_to_hex,hex_to_bin

ldb=LooseObjectDB(sys.argv[1]+'/.git/objects')
PackEntity.create((ldb.stream(sha) for sha in ldb.sha_iter()),sys.argv[1]+'/.git/objects/pack',object_count=ldb.size(),zlib_compression=zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION)
```